# "Nonnegative area of a figure with Infinite height and $0$ base" - functions with logarithmic anti derivatives the only functions to satisfy this?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, logarithms, improper-integrals

Putting the title to math, let's say there's a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \infty$. The limit can be to $0$ or $0^{-}$, but this is for simplicity. For the purpose of getting an infinitely small base, we can have base of width $2\theta - \theta = \theta$ and have $\theta$ approach $0$. The area is, then, $$A = \lim_{\theta \to 0^{+}} \int^{2\theta}_{\theta}f(x)dx$$
Are there any $f(x)$ besides ones which have any logarithms in their antiderivative so that $A$ is a **nonzero constant**?
$f(x) = \frac1x$ and $f(x)=\cot x$ both have logarithms in their antiderivative, and $A = \ln2$ for both.

Point of the question is to find out functions where the "infinite height" doesn't dominate the "$0$ base" (which causes area to be infinite). Also functions that the "$0$ base" doesn't dominate the "infinite height" (which causes area to be $0$). I would be glad to clarify in the comments if anything is confusing.

Comment: Would you accept a function that doesn't have an (elementary) antiderivative?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes

Comment: In that case, I think $f(x)=e^x/x$ will do, and $f(x)=\cos x/x$.

Comment: All of these converge to ln(2), which is quite remarkab le.

Comment: Not all that remarkable, it's because $e^0=\cos0=1$.